How can I make a toggle button in AppGyver (SAP Build Apps)
I'm trying to make an onboarding experience in an app I'm designing (using AppGyver) where the user may select multiple tags for themselves. While I can use a simple checkbox, I would like to instead use toggleable buttons that change color/visual state when selected, but I'm not sure how to do this. I am unable to find any variables or formulas where I can change the style of a button after it is tapped in the logic.
For reference, here is what the buttons look like when they are not toggled/unselected.
Non-toggled/selected buttons
Ideally, the rounded buttons with content in them would change to a blue background with white text after being selected. Could someone please tell me the proper logic flow I need to accomplish this?
I have tried looking into the theme/smart color system in AppGyver, but I can't seem to find any changeable variables that affect the style of the button component itself. I have also tried to use the JavaScript flow component in AppGyver, but again, was unable to find anything useful there.

Please post your code...

@dalelandry Apologies, I shouldn't have added the Javascript tag as that was misleading. I don't have any JS code right now, because I couldn't find anything that AppGyver offered that was useful, and the rest of AppGyver uses their own visual coding system. I have removed the JS tag.
